# Java - matching two unordered lists

Tags: java, collections, matching

I have the following problem: I need to find pairs of the same elements in two lists, which are unordered. The thing about these two lists is that they are "roughly equal" - only certain elements are shifted by a few indexes e.g. (Note, these objects are not ints, I am just using integers in this example):

```
[1,2,3,5,4,8,6,7,10,9]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

My first attempt would be to iterate through both lists and generate two HashMaps based on some unique key for each object. Then, upon the second pass, I would simply pull the elements from both maps. This yields `O(2N)` in space and time.

I was thinking about a different approach: we would keep pointers to the current element in both lists, as well as currentlyUnmatched set for each of the list. the pseudocode would be sth of the following sort:

```
while(elements to process)
    elem1 = list1.get(index1)
    elem2 = list2.get(index2)
    if(elem1 == elem2){ //do work
         ... index1++; 
             index2++;
    }
    else{
        //Move index of the list that has no unamtched elems
        if(firstListUnmatched.size() ==0){
            //Didn't find it also in the other list so we save for later 
            if(secondListUnamtched.remove(elem1) != true)
                firstListUnmatched.insert(elem1)
            index1++
        }
        else { // same but with other index}
    }
```

The above probably does not work... I just wanted to get a rough idea what you think about this approach. Basically, this maintains a hashset on the side of each list, which size << problem size. This should be ~O(N) for small number of misplaced elements and for small "gaps". Anyway, I look forward to your replies.

EDIT: I cannot simply return a set intersection of two object lists, as I need to perform operations (multiple operations even) on the objects I find as matching/non-matching

Comment: A Note on notation: O(2*n) is by definition O(n), and a difference in the number of passes will only be a speed up if the operation in the second case takes no more than double the time...

Comment: Assuming your Lists are unique, you only need to keep a single HashSet of values which haven't matched between lists.  This will be O(M) for space where M is the widest swapped distance.

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanks, that is absolutely true. HaskellElephant - I don't quite see this. In complexity theory I get the fact that O(1000N) is still O(N), but if I do the same traversal of the list 1000 times, it will be 1000 times slower than a single pass, right?

Comment: @Bober02 Basically O(n) doesn't tell you everything you might need to know. It only tells you about how it scales.  e.g. If you have `O(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` may be slower for any realistic use case than `O(N^2)`

Comment: The HashMaps approach is not O(n). Creating a hash involves inserting each value into the map, which itself requires an O(log(n)) lookup, effectively performing an insertion sort. So this is O(n log(n)).

Comment: @PhilH you're wrong. Hash map insertion is ~Constant time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot simply return a set intersection of two object lists, as I need to perform operations (multiple operations even) on the objects I find as matching/non-matching

You can maintain a set of the objects which don't match.  This will be O(M) in space where M is the largest number of swapped elements at any point. It will be O(N) for time where N is the number of elements.

```
interface Listener<T> {
    void matched(T t1);
    void onlyIn1(T t1);
    void onlyIn2(T t2);
}

public static <T> void compare(List<T> list1, List<T> list2, Listener<T> tListener) {
    Set<T> onlyIn1 = new HashSet<T>();
    Set<T> onlyIn2 = new HashSet<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        T t1 = list1.get(i);
        T t2 = list2.get(i);
        if (t1.equals(t2)) {
            tListener.matched(t1);
            continue;
        }
        if (onlyIn2.remove(t1)) 
            tListener.matched(t1);
         else 
            onlyIn1.add(t1);
        if (!onlyIn1.remove(t2))
            onlyIn2.add(t2);
    }
    for (T t1 : onlyIn1)
        tListener.onlyIn1(t1);
    for (T t2 : onlyIn2)
        tListener.onlyIn2(t2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, You can use [Collection.retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) and then iterate over collection that is been retained and do what you have to do.

```
list2.retainAll(list1);
```

Answer (score 0):

All approaches based on maps will be O(n log(n)) at best, because creating the map is an insertion sort. The effect is to do an insertion sort on both, and then compare them, which is as good as it's going to get.

If the lists are nearly sorted to begin with, a sort step shouldn't take as long as the average case, and will scale with O(n log(n)), so just do a sort on both and compare. This allows you to step through and perform your operations on the items that match or do not match as appropriate.